# Form with query builder

Tags: forms, symfony4

I'm trying to achieve a specific form with the query builder, but I get an error when I add the `->select->distinct` to my query builder.

Here is the error:

> Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given

My code:

```
 ->add('ville',
    EntityType::class,
    [   
        'class' => Core::class,
        'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $r)
        {
            return $qb = $r->createQueryBuilder('u')
                           ->select('DISTINCT u.town');
        },
        'choice_label' => 'town',
       ]
    )
```

Comment: EntityType requires that the query_builder function returns a query builder, which in turn has the object of required class (`Core` in your case) and u.town probably is not of class `Core` but rather a string?

Comment: Town is from Core entity :o

Comment: what do you assume `u` is in your query builder? Since the EntityRepository is for `Core` and the default behaviour for `createQueryBuilder` is to provide the base entity (`Core`) the `select` will just cause the query to return the `town` properties of `Core` which probably itself is not `Core`, or do you have self-referencing entities?

Comment: Indeed town is referenced as a string into the Core entity ...

Comment: Should i change the type of town into the Core entity ?

Comment: as far as I can tell, you don't need the `query_builder` option at all.

Comment: that's what I thought, too, so ..what could be my solution ?

Comment: maybe .... remove the query_builder option?

Comment: I cant, because i have something like 458 row and only 8 cities, if i remove the query builder, symfony print one city per row, that is why i was aiming for a distinct option

Comment: Anyway, thanks you a lot for your support

Comment: okay, maybe I'm just majorly confused here. the `EntityType` is for setting an entity on a form field, by providing entities from the database. town, which apparently you want, is not an entity, afaik. Soooo `EntityType` is the wrong form type to begin with. What you probably want is ChoiceType. The problem you get is, that you need an entity manager or at least the appropriate entityrepository to get the towns. you probably have an entity manager outside the form and you could inject it into the form as well via DI.

Comment: I already tried something like this but whitout succes, i cant figure a way to do it .. In the past i used the repository into a function from the form, but the field stayed empty

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201619/discussion-between-jakumi-and-johndoe).

Comment: I added an approach in chat, sadly SO doesn't show notifications for chats ;o/